# How to syntax highlight #+BEGIN_EXPORT HTML environment in org-mode buffer?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Is it possible to get syntax highlight for HTML code within a `#+BEGIN_EXPORT HTML` environment block in org-mode?

I know it is possible to highlight HTML within a `#+BEGIN_SRC` block using [ob-browser](https://github.com/krisajenkins/ob-browser). Is there a way to "extend" such highlighting to other blocks as well?

Comment: It sounds like this might not be exactly what you want, but if you set `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)` in your config, then html in a `#+BEGIN_SRC html` block should have highlighting. There is a nice setup here for dealing with org-mode source code blocks: https://github.com/danielmai/.emacs.d/blob/master/config.org#org-babelsource-blocks

Comment: Yp, within `#+BEGIN_SRC` is not a problem... I was wondering about `#+BEGIN_HTML`. But thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies on the arbitrariness with which Org Mode deals with case sensitivity. I was used to having a `#+BEGIN_HTML` block in Org Mode 8, and that didn't trigger the syntax highlighting. Had I used lowercases as in `#+begin_html`, things might have looked different.

Now, with Org Mode 9, one can get HTML highlight with any of:

```
#+begin_export html
<div>  
</div>
#+end_export

#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<div>  
</div>
#+END_EXPORT
```

But not with:

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT HTML
<div>  
</div>
#+END_EXPORT
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: html_highlighting]

Comment: This does not appear to work in the current version, I get no highlighting regardless how I type it. Any idea for how it can be made to work, or where in the Org Mode source I should look to figure it out myself? I'm running Org Mode from the git repo, `org-version` currently reports version 9.7-pre (release_9.6.7-555-ga1ef64).

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 9.6.1. Did it use to work before and stopped working now? I get syntax highlight without issues. With that said, a lot is currently changing under the hood on org-mode and the org element API, and I've had org-roam breaking and some org-exports as well. Would not exclude the possibility of a bug